# Cauchy sequence in Cartesian Product of two metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(M, d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ be two metric spaces. Let $(M \times N, \sigma)$ denote
the Cartesian product of $M$ and $N$, where
$$
\sigma ((x,y),(u,v))=d(x,u)+\rho(y,v) \,\,\, \forall x,u \in M, y,v \in N
$$

Show that $(x_n, y_n)$ is Cauchy in $(M \times N, \sigma)$ if and only if $x_n$ is Cauchy in $(M, d)$ and $y_n$ is Cauchy in $(N,\rho)$.

If we assume that $x_n$ is Cauchy in $(M, d)$ and $y_n$ is Cauchy in $(N,\rho)$ it is straight forward to show that  $(x_n, y_n)$ is Cauchy in $(M \times N, \sigma)$. However, the converse is not easy, because I do not know how two relate one $\epsilon$ of $(x_n, y_n)$ to two different $\epsilon$'s for $x_n$ and $y_n$.

I mean

$(x_n, y_n)$ is Cauchy

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\,\, \exists \,\,\,n,m \geq N \in \mathbb{N} \,\,\, \text{s.t.} \,\,\,\sigma  ((x_n, y_n),(x_m, y_m)) < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$d(x,u)\leq d(x,u)+\rho(y,v)=\sigma((x,y),(u,v))$$ for every $(x,y),(u,v)\in M\times N$ (the same is true for $\rho(y,v)$). In particular, $d(x,u)\leq\sigma((x,y),(u,v))$ and $\rho(y,v)\leq\sigma((x,y),(u,v))$.

Therefore, if $(x_n,y_n)$ is $\sigma$-Cauchy, then $(x_n)$ is $d$-Cauchy and $(y_n)$ is $\rho$-Cauchy.

Comment: Why maximum of these two is less than their summation?

Comment: @Saeed Because each one is less than their summation. I'll edit it to clarify.